# How to reverse the nested object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, assign

I want to reverse this kind of Object in JS, but I really feel frustrated.
The structure of Object like:

```
input = { a: {b: {c: {d: 'e'}}}};
expected output = {e: {d: {c: {b: 'a'}}}};
```

It's not an array, so reverse function won't work.

I have tried assign function,

```
Object.assign({},input)
// output: { a: {b: {c: [object]}}}
```

or cloneDeep

```
 function cloneDeep(obj){
    if(typeof obj !== "object")
        return obj;
    let resultData = {};
    return recursion(obj, resultData)
 }
 function recursion(obj, data={}){
     for(key in obj){
         if(typeof obj[key] === "object"){
             data[key] = recursion(obj[key]);
         }
         else{
             data[key] = obj[key];
         }
         return data; 
     }
 }
// output: { a: {b: {c: [object]}}}
```

I thought these ways are key to reverse the Object, but I met another problem.
I don't know why the output will be

```
{ a: {b: {c: [object]}}}
```

why not

```
{ a: {b: {c: {d: 'e'}}}} ?
```

Could someone give me an explanation?
Also, give me some ways to reverse the nested object.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you using nodejs?

Comment: No, but I would like to know what's the way to solve this problem by node.js. Actually I do know this problem is from node.js, but I'm not familiar with nodejs. Therefore, I don't even know what kind of keywords to google.

Comment: @NickParsons Do you know why the output will be "{ a: {b: {c: [object]}}}"?

Comment: Node will "simplify" deeply nested objects, it uses `[Object]` after two levels of nesting. But since you said you are not using NodeJS, I'm not sure why this is happening to you. It depends on what console you're using

Answer (score 3):

A recursive approach.

```js
function reverse(o, value) {
    if (!o || typeof o !== 'object') return { [o]: value };
    const [[k, v]] = Object.entries(o);
    return reverse(v, value ? { [k]: value } : k);
}

console.log(reverse({ a: { b: { c: { d: 'e' } } } }));
```

Answer (score 2):

One simple solution:

```js
function reverse(o) {
    let r;
    while (typeof o === 'object') {
        let [k, v] = Object.entries(o)[0]
        r = r ? {[k]: r} : k;
        o = v;
    }
    return {[o]: r}
}


input = {a: {b: {c: {d: 'e'}}}};

console.log(reverse(input))
```

Comment: @Bo-WeiSu: disregard, there's a simpler one

Comment: I've tried your code, but my output is still { e: { d: { c: [Object] } } }. I don't know why? Is the version issue?

Comment: @Bo-WeiSu It's like NickParsons said, it's a cosole.log issue

Comment: Variables not very descriptive